Using find, match and filter with reactive array in VueJS - how do I?
Thought I understood .value but apparently not! :)
This is using VueJS v3 and Composition API. I'm attempting to find the first matching value in a reactive array of people. In reality my array is populated by an API call but the below has an equivalent hard-coded array. I also have a selectedPerson object which is used as a property to a component.
const people = ref([
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Alice'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bob'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Eve'
  },
])

const selectedPerson = ref();

I then elsewhere want to find the one that matches and set it as the value for selectedPerson. Something like this:
function selectPerson(id) {
  selectedPerson.value = people.value.find((person) => {person.id == id})
}

To my understanding value would return an actual array and I could use array functions such as find, match, filter on it. However, the right hand side of the assignment evaluates to undefined.
Is it possible to use find on an array wrapped in a VueJS reactive object? What am I doing wrong? Or do I write my own loop for this? Many thanks for any help.

Could also be the case for a computed depending on how it works

The problem here is in the syntax
selectedPerson.value = people.value.find((person) => {person.id == id}) is not returning anything, it should be :
selectedPerson.value = people.value.find((person) => {return person.id == id}) or simply selectedPerson.value = people.value.find((person) => person.id == id)
You can read more about it here.

Doh, thank you! It's been a couple of years since I've touched Javascript. I need a return statement because of the {...}. It works equally well if I just leave those off as you point out.
I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working and went down a VueJS rabbit hole. Thank you again!
